# JavaScript run multiple async functions one by one

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have function:

```
function getLangFile(name, version) {
  var lang;
  lang = "nothing";
  let url = "./" + version + "/" + name + ".json";
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      setLangToData(data);
    });
}
```

and

```
function setLangToData(data) {
   lang = data
}
```

and i want to run `getLangFile("en_gb", "1.18")`, and when it get the data, run `getLangFile("de_de", "1.18")` and then `someAnotherFunction()`

*I know solution is something with callback or promises, but i don't understand it and i wanna learn it later. I have simple beginner project, but it can't work without this.
Thanks for any help*

Comment: The first 2 function calls seem to be very similar and not dependent on each other, which means you could run both of them at the same time and when both of them are done, run `someAnotherFunction` (or when either is done or when the "de_de" call is done)

Comment: So because you don't want to take the time to learn it you expect us to just write it for you? That is not how SO works. Take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
async function test(){
  const res1 = await getLangFile("en_gb", "1.18");
  const res2 = await getLangFile("de_de", "1.18");
  const res3 = await someAnotherFunction();
}
```

doc:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Might be a good idea to also include the neccessary changes to `getLangFile` since it doesn't return a promise and it won't resolve anything (the nameless function on the question, `version` and `name` are it's 2 parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
const makeHttp = function (url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fetch(url).then((response) => {
      resolve(response.text());
    });
  });
};

(async function () {
  // 1st call
  await makeHttp("./version1/name.json");

  // 2nd call
  await makeHttp("./version2/name.json");
})();
```